# Getting Oauth2.0 access token programatically (not using application.yaml) within a spring app

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I have one client app written in spring boot which fetches the access token.

Application.yaml

```
security:
  basic:
    enabled: false
  oauth2:
    client:
    clientId: MYID
    clientSecret: MYSECRET
    accessTokenUri: ${env.oauth.oauth-url}/token
    userAuthorizationUri: ${env.oauth.oauth-url}/authorize? 
              login_hint=${env.tenant} 
    use-current-uri: false
    pre-established-redirect-uri: http://localhost:8080/app1/login
```

MyConfigurer.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class MYConfigurer
    extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();

}
```

With this code for every http requests it goes for authentication by reading oauth2 configuration from application.yaml. If I make a request to this application's end point from browser, its redirecting me to a page where its asking for email id and password. Then its authenticating the credentials and coming back to application with the accesstoken.

My requirement is to make this authentication happen programatically from java code not through browser where in redirection I am entering emailid and password in the html form. Somehow I want to call these userAuthorizationUri and accessTokenUri using rest template by passing my details and get the access token.